# Check if value exists in a multidimenSional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need help with probably simple code.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id= $row["id"];
    $city = $row["city"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $country = $row["country"];
    $iata = $row["iata"];
    //array here
}
```

I want to check if country is already in array, and if yes, then add city into exactly that country array

something like:

```
$result{
  'United Kingdom' => 'London', 'Oxford'
}
```

Comment: The second snippet you provided is invalid... how can we possibly know what you want if you're providing invalid code? Also, are you trying to get "London" and "Oxford" in an array under the UK? If so, make an array (so that it becomes 2d), not another array entry in the first dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array with countries as index and an array of cities as values, so:

```
$arr = Array(){'uk' => Array(){'london', 'Oxford'},
               'foo' => Array(){'bar'}
       };
```

try this:

```
var $arr = Array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id= $row["id"];
    $city = $row["city"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $country = $row["country"];
    $iata = $row["iata"];

    $arr[$country][] = $city;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably what you need:

```
if (isset($result[$country]) {
    $result[$country][] = $city;
}
else {
    $result[$country] = array($city);
}
```